# My code runs then sometimes it has error "Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."

Tags: matlab, matrix

This is my code and I understand you have to have dimensions of matrix equal to line up which is why I transpose y to make it a column and both have 21 rows but sometimes the code runs when I publish but then after one time of running it persistently then hits this error if I try to run it again. It says error on line disp([t,y])

```
%Define parameters         
A=1250; %m^2        
Q=450; %m^3/d       
a=150;        
y(1)=0;        
t=[0:0.5:10]';          
y=y';          
disp('        t            y')          
disp('----------------------')            
disp([t,y])           
%Set loop in (Eulers method) for the amount of steps we want to do to
%find our estimated solution       
for i=1:20           
y(i+1)=y(i)+((3*(Q/A)*sin(t(i)).^2)-(a*(1+y(i)).^1.5/A))*0.5;             
end             
%generate plot for data           
plot(t,y)          
title('Plot of y vs t')               
xlabel('time')              
ylabel('y')
```

Comment: What language is this? Matlab?

Comment: yes, this is matlab. Though my issue now is disp([t,y]) I transposed it to be two columns to create a table when displayed but gives me an error "Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.”. Could really use help, sometimes when I run it, the whole file runs smoothly but always the second time I get that error with the exact same file.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific error (and line). You should also tag it with the `matlab` tag. Otherwise, not very many people will look at your question, and barely any with any expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `y` only has one element when you attempt to display it.

You're constructing `[t,y]` which is a concatenation of two elements - `t` and `y`. But `t` is a vector of some length (21), whereas you have not initialized `y` to be anything.

If you really do want to display `y` before it's been set, you can initialize it to zero using y(1:21) = 0

But why do you want to display `y` and `t` before you've calculated your estimated solution, anyway?